# CodeIgniter XSS Filter issues

Tags: php, codeigniter

application/controlers/welcome.php

```
<?php
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        if ($val = $this->input->post('test'))
        {
            var_dump($val);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        }
    }
}
```

application/views/weclome_message.php

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="test" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Output with XSS filter ON and input %9c:

```
string(1) "œ"
```

Output with XSS filter OFF and input %9c:

```
string(3) "%9c"
```

I was expecting the first one to be the same value as the second one. What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think thats happening because of

```
$str = rawurldecode($str);
```

in xss_clean function. Take a look at line 346:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Security.php

You could try to comment that line and see what happens then.